# jQuery idTabs plugin hover feature problem

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery [idTabs](http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/) pluging. I want to give hover feature and use divs with this feature. Default settings are working with click event. How can I change this feature.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure how specifically you want to use divs, but to achieve the "hover" effect your talking about, use the following code:

```
$("...").idTabs("!mouseover");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="adv1" class="usual"> 
    <span>
            <div><a href="#t1">Tab 1</a></div> 
            <div><a href="#t2">Tab 2</a></div> 
            <div><a href="#t3">Tab 3</a></div> 
    </span>

    <div id="t1">This is tab 1.</div> 
        <div id="t2">More content in tab 2.</div> 
        <div id="t3">Tab 3 is always last!</div> 
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $("#adv1 span").idTabs({ start:1, change:false },true);
</script>
```

pretty junky script, why not consider the real tabs http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Comment: How can I implement the code into this system? I've tried but I failed.

<ul class="idTabs"> 
  <li><a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#other"><span>Others</span></a></li   
</ul> 

<div id="contact" class="idTabs-div">
 Contact content.
</div>

<div id="other" class="idTabs-div">
 Contact content.
</div>

CSS--> .idTabs-div {display:none}